# Which block yield calls when used in each method defined for mixin Enumerable?

Tags: ruby, block, yield, inject

```
class VowelFinder 
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(string) 
    @string = string
  end

  def each
    @string.scan(/[aeiou]/) do |vowel| 
      yield vowel
    end 
  end
end

vf = VowelFinder.new("the quick brown fox jumped") 
vf.inject(:+)
```

The above code scans for vowels in a string and puts them in a single string using inject.

The thing that I am not able understand is what block yield is calling in the each method. As I understand yield requires a block to work which I am not able to see anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The ruby doc tells you how it works out

> Enumerable
>
> The Enumerable mixin provides collection classes with several traversal and searching methods, and with the ability to sort. The class must provide a method each, which yields successive members of the collection. If Enumerable#max, #min, or #sort is used, the objects in the collection must also implement a meaningful <=> operator, as these methods rely on an ordering between members of the collection.

Since your class `VowelFinder` includes `Enumerable` you have to implement `each` using `yield` and the rest of the magic of the implementation of `Enumerable#inject` will make `inject(:+)` work.

The block is an implementation detail of `Enumerable` and thus not directly accessible, but created by the `inject` call.